# Make multipart/form-data request with json

Tags: web-services, vbscript, asp-classic

I am calling a web service from Classic ASP/VBScript.  The call expects 3 parameters, 1 which is form data and 2 which are optional file data.  Currently not sending the file data.

The form data is multiple fields, wrapped up in json.
So I'm setting the content-type on the ServerXMLHTTP object to be multipart/form-data, and I'm creating the json segment as such and sending it as the data

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
"Token": "...",
"FirstName": "First Name",
```

I keep getting Request must be Content-type: multipart/form-data.
I've tried adding a boundary and same thing.
I know I can do this in C# using MultipartFormDataContent, but it has to be Classic unfortunately.

What's the correct way to send?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25144525/edit) to show the ASP code for creating the `ServerXMLHTTP` object and for building the form data to POST?

Comment: The `ServerXMLHTTP` `Content-Type` header will need to be `multipart/form-data` and the data you send will have to be converted into binary. Here is an example code from a web service that shows a classic asp implementation that is specifically for images but the principles still apply - [Construct multipart/form-data POST Request](http://matchengine.tineye.com/docs/code/classic_asp_sample.html#id1)